# Inconsistent result with JPA streams after upgrading to Hibernate 6.x / Spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, orm

We have an application doing some batch processing, were some statistics are calculated from order history. We fetch around 500k records from a Postgres database when doing this. The data is basically only orders and order details joined to orders like this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<OrderDetails> getOrderDetails() {
    return orderDetails;
}
```

We have a query defined like this

```
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "5000"))
Stream<CreatedOrder> streamAllDistinctByCreatedBetween(long startEpochMillis, long endEpochMillis);
```

We then perform the calculations like this. The flush/clear piece was added to avoid allocating too much memory for the data which we no longer needed for the calculations.

```
@Transactional
public void calculateOrderStats() {
    try (Stream<OrderDetails> orderDetailsStream = createdOrderRepository.streamAllDistinctByCreatedBetween(periodStart, periodEnd)) {
        orderDetailsStream.forEach(orderDetails -> {
            //Do calculations..
            if(count % 1000 == 0) {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

We have been running this code with Spring boot 2.7.1/Hibernate 5.6.9.Final for quite some time. But after upgrading to Spring boot 3.0.0/Hibernate 6.1.5.Final, we have started seeing different results for these calculations. We basically calculate what items are frequently bought together, and we are getting different results when running the old and the new versions side by side.

After much investigation, we realized that the difference comes from the fact that we are no longer getting the same data from the stream and the only thing we can do to get the same results with with 6.x as with 5.x is to

1. Remove the stream() and collect all orders straight to a list, increasing memory consumtion by A LOT.
   or
2. Remove the flush/clear piece of code, i.e.

```
if(count % 1000 == 0) {
   entityManager.clear();
}
```

Any ideas as to why would the entityManager.clear() work with Hibernate 5.x and cause these issues with 6.x? We haven't been able to find an explanation in the 6.0 migration guide.

Comment: "we have started seeing different results for these calculations" - would you mind clarifying what does it mean?

Comment: Sure, I've updated with some details

Comment: Do your calculations depend on the presentation order of elements in the stream? If so, it might be worth adding an `ORDER BY` to the query.

Then, have you checked that the SQL generated between old and new deployments is 1:1?

Comment: They do not depend on the order, no. Will try with ORDER BY and see if that helps. 
The generated SQL is identical, except the column aliases which are apparently not needed any longer in Hibernate 6.